# I was told to use swing to design this. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Tags: swing

I am new to java so pls help me
the requirement is like this.

```
*-----------------------------------------------*
| label A     |   field A                       | 
| label B     |   field B                       |
| label C     |   field C                       |
| label D     |   field D                       |   
|                                               |
| Button1 Button2 Button3 Button4               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|           JTABLE                              |
|                                               |
*-----------------------------------------------*
```

i have tried with this code

' here i am creating Group layout'

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

`creating horizontal Group`

layout.setHorizontalGroup(

```
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)

        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)

        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)

        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(txtitem, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(txtprice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100,javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4) 
                            .addComponent(txtquantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnupdate)//,javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE)//,javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btndelete,javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnlist,javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnadd)//,javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE)

                            .addComponent(txtreorder)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)  )
                    )
                    )
                    );
```

'here is a vertical layout'

```
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
               .addComponent(txtitem, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
               .addComponent(txtprice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(txtquantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
               // .addComponent(btnadd))
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(btnadd,javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnupdate,javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addComponent(btndelete,javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addComponent(btnlist,javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addComponent(txtreorder, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            //.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            //.addContainerGap()
            )));



}
```

Comment: You seem also to be new in StackOverflow, but this is not the way things work. You will have to post what you have tried so far, so the community can suggest solutions. Otherwise, as you probable have discovered by now, you will receive negative points by many trigger happy members.

Comment: Seems you need to examine [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: Holy crap is that a lot of method chaining. Are you scared of semicolons or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you uploaded is impossible to read and use without a GUI designer. Try to avoid using a GUI designer while you are in a learning phase. During learning it is always best to stick to standard simple layouts.

In order to keep your code simple, you could try this approach:

[image: Frame mockup]

The resulting JFrame will look like this: 
       [image: Preview Design]

You may have to do a little tweaking with the JLabel Horizontal alignment in order to get things right.

This sample code should do the work:

```
    public class LayoutSample extends JFrame {

        public LayoutSample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        p4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        l1 = new JLabel("Label1");
        l2 = new JLabel("Label2");
        l3 = new JLabel("Label3");
        l4 = new JLabel("Label4");
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf4 = new JTextField();
        p3.add(l1);
        p3.add(tf1);
        p3.add(l2);
        p3.add(tf2);
        p3.add(l3);
        p3.add(tf3);
        p3.add(l4);
        p3.add(tf4);

        b1 = new JButton("Button1");
        b2 = new JButton("Button2");
        b3 = new JButton("Button3");
        b4 = new JButton("Button4");
        p4.add(b1);
        p4.add(b2);
        p4.add(b3);
        p4.add(b4);

        t = new JTable();
        t.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
                }
        ));
        sc = new JScrollPane(t);

        p5.add(sc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.add(p3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p2.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(p5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p1);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutSample().setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    private JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4;
    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    private JScrollPane sc;
    private JTable t;
}
```

Comment: :can u please give some references to do this coz i stuck at this for long time so pls help me

Comment: Check the code against the mockup-form. You probably will have to do some studying in order to understand the concepts. Check the sun-oracle tutorial.